# How to connect PHP with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need help connecting PHP with SQL Server, or is this trying to get water and oil together? I leave a comment in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-output-parameters-using-the-sqlsrv-driver

Playing with this code (URL) I get this error:

> Variable parameter 2 not passed by reference (prefaced with an &). Output or bidirectional variable parameters (SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT and SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT) passed to sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query should be passed by reference, not by value

If I use

```
$params = array(

array($lastName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN), array(&$salesYTD, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT) ); 

echo $salesYTD;
```

the value showed is a long text (all PHP code)

Comment: which version of the sqlsvr driver you are using?

Comment: Have you tried the samples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php

Comment: Yes, I try this solution but I get the error.

PHP version=7.0.15



SQLSRV version=php7.0-sybase

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the problem, my guess is you code is correct with &.

I think you didn't initialize the variable before use in the query. 
Initialize it like this:

```
$salesYTD = 0.0;
```

This sets the internal datatype in PHP to float.

or

You need to specify the PHP type in query:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-specify-php-data-types

Answer (score -1):

NOT AT ALL, we have done it with great success using freeTDS.

take a look at http://www.freetds.org/userguide/php.htm It looks complicated but honestly it isn't really and it works well.

found this nice tutorial for Linux : http://www.informaticapressapochista.com/linux/connect-php-code-ms-sql-server-freetds/

We use it on MAC with brew

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: downvote because not helping answer. why to switch to an other db provider?